# Receiving sensor_msgs::Image as data member in a ros message

Tags: c++, ros

I am trying to receive a data structure contains sensor_msgs::Image as data member as declared by me in frame.msg

```
std_msgs/Header header
sensor_msgs/Image color
geometry_msgs/Vector3 translation
```

However the callback function below gives a compilation error of
" no matching function for call to ‘toCvShare(const _color_type&, const char [5])"

```
void frameCallback( frame_info::frameConstPtr& msg)
{

    cv::imshow("UserInterface", cv_bridge::toCvShare(msg->color, "bgr8")->image);
    cv::waitKey(1);
}
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/cv_bridge/html/c++/namespacecv__bridge.html) there are two variants of `toCvShare` from which [one](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/cv_bridge/html/c++/namespacecv__bridge.html#a57ce555fdef0034a7aa60b1b58be615c) needs

> A shared_ptr to an object owning the sensor_msgs::Image

and [the other](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/cv_bridge/html/c++/namespacecv__bridge.html#aafa38a1d9be98d9efaefe45fd873133c)

> A shared_ptr to a sensor_msgs::Image message

You are providing neither one nor the other.

In your case, the first option should work, which expects the image as first parameter and the shared_ptr to the object owning the image (which is `msg`) as second parameter:

```
cv_bridge::toCvShare(msg->color, msg, "bgr8")
```